# display empty table row

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display 10 rows per page.If the data present in the table it is display now.Two records in the table that two records are display now.But I want to display the 8 empty row in the table.I have some confusion with this concept.

[image]

Now the screen shot display two records which is in db.With this I want to display 8 more empty rows.

```
while($fet=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1)) {
    $id=$fet['c_id'];
    $address=$fet['address'];
    $chk=$fet["c_name"];

    if($chk!='') {      
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td style='align:center'><a href='client_view.php?cid=".$fet["c_id"]."'>".$fet["c_name"]."</a></td>";  
        echo "<td style='align:center'><a class='ima' href='client_details.php?cid=".$fet["c_id"]."'><img src='image/edit1.png' alt='edit' style='width:20px; height:20px' title=Edit></a></td><td style='align:center'>
            <a class='ima' href='clients.php?del=".$fet["c_id"]."'><img src='image/delete1.png' alt='delete' style='width:20px;height:20px' title=Delete></a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    } else {
        echo "<tr><td><\td><td></td></tr>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks like you want to use `c_name` to decide if you need an empty row, while your explanation sounds like you want to show empty table rows, if the database did not contain 10 results. Which one is it?

Comment: if the $fet fetches only two rows, your condition wont work

Comment: If two rows in the db I want to display 10 rows with 2 data rows and 8 empty rows.Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count rows you found by SQL query and then put there empty rows, if needed.

```
while($fet=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1)) {
    ...
}

if (mysql_num_rows($sql1) < 10) {
    $empty_rows = 10 - mysql_num_rows($sql1);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $empty_rows; $i++) {
        echo '<tr><td><td>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$i=0;
while($fet=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1)){
    $i++;
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td style='align:center'><a href='client_view.php?cid=".$fet["c_id"]."'>".$fet["c_name"]."</a></td>";  
    echo "<td style='align:center'><a class='ima' href='client_details.php?cid=".$fet["c_id"]."'><img src='image/edit1.png' alt='edit' style='width:20px; height:20px' title=Edit></a></td><td style='align:center'><a class='ima' href='clients.php?del=".$fet["c_id"]."'><img src='image/delete1.png' alt='delete' style='width:20px;height:20px' title=Delete></a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

while ($i < 10) {
    $i++;
    echo "<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>";
}
```